# use sphinx to generated pdf by latex, how to change the chapter font size and secion font size?

Tags: python-sphinx, xelatex

When I use **sphinx** to generated **pdf** , I do not know how to set package to change the chapter font size and section font size,main text font size??

How can I do this ?

Comment: Are you using rst2pdf or latexpdf?

Comment: I am using latexpdf